# onTouchListener() in Android not called after including ImageView from BaseActivity-XML

Tags: java, android, xml, inheritance, ontouchlistener

The following code shows an abstract Activity (AppActivity), other Activities have to extend from. There is already a layout defined, but inherits nothing more then including a round button (extending ImageView).

MainActivity defines an own layout, which has to include the button mentioned before. Looking at my current results, the Button sucessfully is inherited and shown, can not be null

Nevertheless, the onTouchListener() attached to this ImageView never gets called from perspective "MainActivity". Note, that i return true if MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and UP occurs. So this cant be the cause. Any suggestions?

**Abstract Activity with CircleButton (extends ImageView) inclusive onTouchListener()**

```
public abstract class AppActivity extends Activity {

    public CircleButton circleButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice_btn_layout);

        circleButton = (CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.voiceControlBtn);

        circleButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("TOUCH", "");
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ButtonGotPressed();
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    circleButton.ButtonGotReleased();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

**Activity extending from AppActivity**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppActivity implements ICadeCommand {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(eu.alfred.batterywarnerapp.R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

**activity_main.xml (for MainActivity)**

```
<RelativeLayout .../>

    <include layout="@layout/voice_btn_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**voice_btn_layout.xml (for AppActivity)**

```
    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <packagename.CircleButton
                ...
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `OnTouchListener` for `circleButton` in `R.layout.voice_btn_layout`.

When you call `setContentView()` in `MainActivity`, you replace the layout `R.layout.voice_btn_layout` with `eu.alfred.batterywarnerapp.R.layout.activity_main`. Therefore the `onTouch()` method for `circleButton` in `AppActivity` is not called because the `circleButton` shown on the screen is not the same as the `circleButton` in `AppActivity`.

You can test if this is indeed the case by adding an extra line in `AppActivity`

```
public abstract class AppActivity extends Activity {

public CircleButton circleButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_btn_layout);

    circleButton = (CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.voiceControlBtn);
    circleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);     // ADD THIS LINE 
    circleButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ...
```

You should notice that `circleButton` is still visible thus showing that the `circleButton` displayed on screen is not the same as the one in `AppActivity`.

Comment: Sure i am "replacing" the layout? I am just including it. activity_main.xml is that special button layout, expect its now wrapped by another RelativeLayout

Comment: @GaryKlasen Yes i am pretty sure that `R.layout.voice_btn_layout` is replaced by `activity_main.xml`. `setContentView()` is just inflate a new layout and set it as the layout for this `Activity`. Yes you did add a listener in `AppActivity`'s `onCreate()` but when you call `setContentView()` again in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`, a new `eu.alfred.batterywarnerapp.R.layout.activity_main` layout containing a new `R.layout.voice_btn_layout` is inflated and replace the previously set `R.layout.voice_btn_layout`.

Comment: So how may i include it without overwriting the reference?

Comment: @GaryKlasen by not calling `setContentView()` in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` although I doubt this is what you are trying to achieve. If you want to call `setOnTouchListener()` on all subclass of `AppActivity` I suggest that you put your set listener codes in a seperate method (e.g. `setupCircleButton()` ) in `AppActivity` and call `super.setupCircleButton()` in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` **AFTER** `setContentView()`.